# Express + Postman, req.body is empty

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I know this has been asked multiple times, but I have been looking around and still can't find an answer to my problem.

Here is my code, I make sure to use and configure body parser before defining the routes. I'm only using .json() with bodyParser because right now I'm only testing a POST function, but I've even tried with app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});

app.post('/itemSearch', function(req, res) {
    //var Keywords = req.body.Keywords;
    console.log("Yoooooo");
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send("yay");
});
```

Here is how I use Postman to test this route.
[image]

and here is the response I receive

```
Node app is running at localhost:5000
Yoooooo
{ host: 'localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '146',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  origin: 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynJtRFnukjOQDaHgU',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36',
  'postman-token': '984b101b-7780-5d6e-5a24-ad2c89b492fc',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' }
{}
```

At this point I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

AFAIK you need to use the Body-Parser : https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
bodyParser = require('body-parser').json();
app.post('/itemSearch', bodyParser, function(req, res) {
  //var Keywords = req.body.Keywords;
  console.log("Yoooooo");
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send("yay");
});
```

Then try with PostMan setting the body as `raw` json:

```
{
  "test": "yay"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The problem was that with PostMan I was sending the request through form data

Comment: I need to send through `form-data` for attaching files, getting empty body. how to solve it?

Comment: The fact that this is in a separate package makes me wonder if the I'm taking for building an API is right. Is it not natural to expect a body for most update or put requests?

Comment: Make sure you have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json` as well.

Answer (score 109):

After spending a few hours I realized need to change the Raw type in postman to JSON[image]

Comment: Just in case someone looks here, be certain that you're using Postman's JSON and not Javascript header. I had Javascript and it won't work.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !!

Comment: i was nearly tilting, thanks so much! and dear postman devs, wtf? this is the only task you need to be able to manage... how can you hide it like this? ;(

Comment: Oh!! These silly mistakes -_-... Thanks for the answer

Comment: In my case, I've had to add also a "Content-Length" header for some reason. Otherwise, the request wasn't successful although it was the same as my curl request, which worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for saving my life....

Comment: For me, I had created a new postman test and duplicated a previous request with JSON body. For some reason, it didn't recognize it as JSON until I switched to plain text and back again to JSON. So if this still doesn't work for you, try switching the raw type even if it's already on JSON.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add an answer, as was seeming to have trouble getting sending as `form-data` to work, even if I was adding `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to the Header (this was listed as correct header type in docs). I wonder if because using BodyParser in express, data has to come in as JSON raw. I swear I got `form-data` to work before, alas.

Here's how I was able to get `req.body` not to be empty:

1. Make sure in "Headers" tab, you have this key value pair setup:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

[image: set Content-Type as application/json]

Side note: interesting link to stack overflow article on [all available header content type values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704300/6685623).

2. In "Body" tab, make sure `raw` radio button is selected, and far right dropdown has `JSON` selected:

[image: Select raw and JSON]

3. Now if I console log `req.body` in my express app, I see printed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 // create application/json parser
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
    // parse some custom thing into a Buffer
    app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));
    // parse an HTML body into a string
    app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));
    // parse an text body into a string
    app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/plain' }));
    // create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 2):

After spending  2 days and hours I realized that I need to change postman : Text to JSON

1. If you're using express 16.4 and up,
   make sure you have :

   ```
   const express = require("express");
   require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/.env" });
   require("./config/db");
   const app = express();
   const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");

   app.use(express.json()); //this is the build in express body-parser 
   app.use(                //this mean we don't need to use body-parser anymore
     express.urlencoded({
       extended: true,
     })
   );    
   //routes
   app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);

   // connect to the server
   app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
     console.log(`lestening port ${process.env.PORT}`);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve it By Adding `"type":"text"` to `urlencoded` item int the exported collection `json` file generated by postman. I observe it because there are some of my request is successfully done. The difference is the missing `type` field in the json generated postman collection file. This problem also happen to my teammate.

before (failed request): 

`"body": {
    "mode": "urlencoded",
    "urlencoded": [
        {
            "key": "email",
            "value": "{{userEmail}}"
        },
        {
            "key": "password",
            "value": "{{userPassword}}"
        }
    ]
}`

after (successful request): 

`"body": {
    "mode": "urlencoded",
    "urlencoded": [
        {
            "key": "email",
            "value": "{{userEmail}}",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "key": "password",
            "value": "{{userPassword}}",
            "type": "text"
        }
    ]
}`

I also write parser script in javascript language to handle it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let object = require(process.argv[2]);

function parse(obj) {
    if(typeof obj === 'string') return;
    for(let key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(key === 'urlencoded') {
                let body = obj[key];
                for(let i = 0;i < body.length;i++) {
                    body[i].type = "text";
                }
            }
            else parse(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}

parse(object);
fs.writeFile('ParsedCollection.json', JSON.stringify(object, null, '\t'), function(err){
    //console.log(err);
});
```

Just run it in terminal `node parser.js <json postman collection file path>` and it will output in `ParsedCollection.json` file. After that import this file into postman.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending the request as form-data, use urlencoded() middleware from `express` or `body-parser`.

```js
bodyParser = require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }); 
app.post('/itemSearch', bodyParser, function(req, res) {
  //var Keywords = req.body.Keywords;
  console.log("Yoooooo");
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send("yay");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello You don't need body parser

```
const StringDecoder = require("string_decoder").StringDecoder;

 _server.post("/users", function (req, res) {
    const decoder = new StringDecoder();
    let buffer = "";
    req.on("data", function (data) {
      buffer += decoder.write(data);
    });
    req.on("end", function () {
      try {
        console.log(JSON.parse(buffer));
        res.json({ success: "ok });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  });
```