# Receiving empty data in controller file when consoling the req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

## userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    pic: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

## userControllers.js

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req", req.body);
  const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please Enter all the Fields" });
  }

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExists) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "User already exists" });
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    pic,
  });

  if (user) {
    return res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "User creation failed" });
  }
});

module.exports = { registerUser };
```

## userRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { registerUser } = require("../controllers/userControllers");

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser);

module.exports = router;
```

## server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // to accept json data

app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const server = app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}...`.yellow.bold)
);
```

## Sending Data Format:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "john@gmail.com",
  "password": "securepassword"
}
```

## Issue Description:

I'm encountering an issue while trying to retrieve data sent via a POST request to the /api/user/ endpoint. In the userControllers.js file, I'm attempting to log the received data using console.log("req", req.body);, but the output shows an empty object {}.

This issue occurs even when sending valid data in the specified format to the endpoint using Postman. I've ensured that the necessary controllers, routes, and model files are correctly set up as described in the provided file structure.

Despite following the correct procedure for sending data, I'm unable to retrieve the expected data in the userControllers.js file. I seek assistance in resolving this issue to successfully retrieve the posted data from the request body.

Comment: Looks like you need to set the correct postman settings when sending JSON. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38436905/21972629).

Answer (score 0):

The express built-in json body parser only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option, by default 'application/json'. If you don't send the content type header with your request the body will be ignored.

[Methods express.json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json:%7E:text=express.json(%5Boptions%5D))

Comment: @Keith OP says and i quote "I'm attempting to log the received data using console.log('req', req.body);, but the output shows an empty object {}." how is that refering to res.json() exactly?

Comment: Yeah, just spotted that as I posted.. :)

Comment: It's with him talking about POSTMAN that threw me.