# .net core Web API - 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm building a .net core WebApi while following a course. I'm trying to upload photos, but I keep getting the error

> 415 - Unsupported file type

Here is the relevant controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhotoForUser(int userId, [FromForm] PhotoForCreationDto photoForCreationDTO)
{
    if(userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
        return Unauthorized();

    var userFromRepo = await _repo.GetUser(userId);

    var file = photoForCreationDTO.File;

    var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

    if(file.Length > 0)
    {
        using(var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(file.Name, stream),
                Transformation = new Transformation().Width(500).Height(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
            };

            uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
        }
    }

    photoForCreationDTO.Url = uploadResult.Uri.ToString();
    photoForCreationDTO.PublicId = uploadResult.PublicId;

    var photo =_mapper.Map<Photo>(photoForCreationDTO);

    if(!userFromRepo.Photos.Any(u => u.IsMain))
        photo.IsMain = true;

    userFromRepo.Photos.Add(photo);

    if(await _repo.SaveAll())
    {
        var photoToReturn = _mapper.Map<PhotoForReturnDto>(photo);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new { id = photo.Id}, photoToReturn);
    }

    return BadRequest("Could not add the photo");
}
```

I have no idea what the error is? Any ideas?

[Response and Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ourXG.png)

Comment: Have you checked what kind of media type formatters are in your pipeline?

Comment: Where would I check that? I'm new to .net core!

Comment: This is kind of a big subject. You might want to search for "asp.net core media type formatter". I don't think you've presented enough info here for this question to be answered. It's likely none of the code above is even being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your c# code sends a HTTP POST request under the hood. This request has a Content-Type header. You get a 415 if the Content-Type does not match the actual content type of the body of your POST request.

Try attaching a Content-Type header with the appropriate type. For a list of possible type values, see [What are all the possible values for HTTP "Content-Type" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714383/what-are-all-the-possible-values-for-http-content-type-header)