# Which content-types are supported by html5 object tag?

Tags: html, html-object

I am trying to embed uploaded files into a page using object tag. When using in Chrome on Linux, text files and pdf are correctly embedded. On the other hand doc, ppt, etc. are not displayed and downloaded instead. What determines which files are displayed and which are not? Is it possible to detect supported types, so I can avoid displaying the preview? Is it different in other browsers and OS?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714383/what-are-all-the-possible-values-for-http-content-type-header

Comment: Thank you! Do you know some further information regarding the follow up questions?