# PHP Force Download

Tags: php, header, force-download

I am new to php and ajax. Im trying to force download a file from a list of documents. The functions below gets triggered using an ajax call after a button click.

```
function downloadDocument($filename) {

$file_path = ".........../DocUploader/Uploads/" . $filename;

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'" . $filename);

    readfile($file_path);


} else{
    echo "Document does not exist";
}};
```

[image: Code for downloading file]

Instead of downloading the file, I assume I am getting the file content as a response. I would really appreciate any advise on what I should do.

[image: Response I get]

Comment: remove `echo "File exists";` line

Comment: @IłyaBursov still the same response

Comment: oh and content type should be `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @IłyaBursov I tried that as well, it still doesn't download the file but gives a different response
https://imgur.com/a/K4b7979

Comment: Please post your code that have problem as TEXT not image.

Comment: @vee Thank you for the response. I'm not quite sure where I have the problem but I have posted the code piece in the image.

Comment: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'" . $filename);` should be `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'" . $filename . "\"");`

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thank you for the response. Tried that. Still no change in the response

Comment: A regular file download is never going to automatically happen when using AJAX! No matter what headers you set.

Comment: don't forget to `exit();` after `readfile();`.

Answer (score 0):

First remove any echo's or output to the browser before sending any `header`, ie. remove the `echo "File exists";`

The file name should be encapsulated in quotations, ie. `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.ext"`

```
<?php
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');

readfile($file_path);
```

Keep in mind to set correct `Content-type` based on the real kind of the downloaded document, see topic [What are all the possible values for HTTP "Content-Type" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714383/what-are-all-the-possible-values-for-http-content-type-header)

You can dynamically detect the MIME type using PHP function [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type)

And reference for [PHP header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).