# How to set the content-type of http response header to application/msword in java?

Tags: java, rest

I have tried this but somehow it's not taking/reflecting the changes in the browser

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("applicaiton", "msword");
        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(mediaType);
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291027/what-is-the-use-of-response-setcontenttypetext-html-in-servlet

Comment: Here they're not returning anything. Return type of the method is void there. But in my case i have to return a template. An html template basically. My function need to be able to do below actions
1. set content-type of response header
2.return a template